# Too Much Swapping, even though RAM is ~75% Empty

Tags: hard-drive, memory, centos, swap, postgresql

I have a VPS with 9GB RAM, 300GB HDD, 3 GB Swap, 7 Cores.
The OS is CentOS 5.7 Final.

I have postgres9.0 running on my machine, with proper tuning done (at least by book/wiki of PostgreSQL).

What happens is most of the times when some complex query run (by complex I mean select with maximum 3 Joins), eventhough ~75% of my RAM is unused there is ~99% swapping is happening.

**EDIT :** the free RAM i am mentioning here is calculated by (free + buffered + cached)
The actually free shown by 'free -m' is hardly ~2%.
So correct me if I am wrong here in the first place.

Plus it screws up my disk IO which is most of the time reaching ~100% and slows down everything else.
(I tend to believe something's wrong with my disk.)

I dont understand the reason of this much of swapping happening.
Is it because of context switching?? 
Most of the time my processors are idle, while the IO wait goes upto 30% during pick times.

Would appreciate if some can shed some light on it.

Thanks.

Comment: `shared_buffers` is accounted for in `free` as `buffers/cache` ... so keep that in mind when considering your "free" memory.

Comment: but if i am not wrong shared_buffers are per process in OS and for postgres they are per connection.
Kindly correct if i am wrong. thanks

Comment: How big is the database? If `free -m` says you have 2% *free*, then you have 2% free. Everything else that's not application memory is disk cache, which will be used to cache the database if it's available. Don't assume that the "75%" of memory isn't already filled to the brim with your database tables - Your query might just be hitting the ones that didn't fit into the cache.

Comment: Database is ~165GB.
And indeed what happens is the table which I need for most of the queries say ~99% of them is ~150GB of it (including indexes)

Comment: @indyaah `shared_buffers` are global in PostgreSQL; they're allocated once as shared memory by the postmaster, and shared among all connections. There is one process per connection. Maybe you're thinking of `work_mem`, which is private to each backend? It's actually per-sort, not per-connection, though.

Comment: Actually I believe the 'free' aka available memory in Linux is free plus cached MINUS buffered. This is because free+cached is too high as it includes a bit of data (the buffered memory) that needs to be written to disk before it can be reallocated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux kernel decides to put memory pages in swap when they're not used too frequently, even when it has some memory available. You can tweak this behaviour by adjusting the 'swappiness' of the memory manager by doing

```
$ echo 50 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

where `50` is a value between `0` (swap least possible) and `100` (swap out as much as you like).

See also [Wikipedia: swappiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) to read more about this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may be looking at the right value, but just in case you aren't and for those others who are looking at the wrong figure.

```
$ free -mt
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2027       1953         73          0         66       1501
-/+ buffers/cache:        385       1641 <---- this value is actually free
Swap:         4086          0       4086
Total:        6113       1954       4159
```

This is from our head office stock/erp system for 40ish head office staff and coordinating 9 satellite branch stock/erp systems, 80% (1641MB) of our ram usage is considered free, but rather than being wasted is doing something useful and acting as buffers/cache.